# Is there a name for this kind of graph?

Tags: graphs, terminology

Is there a name for the DAG obtained from a directed graph by collapsing together the strongly connected components?

Comment: This DAG is minor of original graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graph you describe is called the [**condensation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of the original graph.